# Inserting line feature class values to point feature class in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, line, attribute-joins

I have two feature classes. A line feature class and a point feature class.
The point feature class snaps to the line and the line feature class splits at points. I want to insert the value of Shape_Length in each point automatically. For example the point 1 should have 1087.7382 and so on. The end point must have a zero value.

How can I insert the values in Point feature class?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solve my problem by automating two processes with arcpy:

1. Create Start vertices to point for the line feature class using [Vertices to Point Tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/feature-vertices-to-points.htm)
2. [Spatial Join](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm) the Start Start Points with Point feature class.